# How to pull data sitekey from a webpage that has recaptcha

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

The code below is the script that I want to pull the "sitekey" from. I want to be able to return this sitekey and use for various tasks.

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    var recaptchaCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
        sitekey: "6LeoeSkTAAAAAA9rkZs5oS82l69OEYjKRZAiKdaF",
        size: (window.innerWidth > 320) ? 'normal' : 'compact',
        callback: 'onCaptchaSuccess',
      });
    };

    var onCaptchaSuccess = function() {
      var event;

      try {
        event = new Event('captchaSuccess', {bubbles: true, cancelable: 
true});
      } catch (e) {
        event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('captchaSuccess', true, true);
      }

      window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

//]]>
</script>
```

I want to be able to pull the sitekey from the code above.
Is this possible?

Comment: You already have the sitekey, no need to pull it out of there

Comment: No, lol @AdamH, I'm trying to pull that variable out from the javascript and use it in my python code. There are different sitekeys sometimes

Comment: Same, I'm looking for a solution